# mongoDB Query not returning anything

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.studentSeminar.insert({
  seminar: {
    seminarID: "sem004",
    seminarDescription: "In-memory Database.",
    seminarDate: "2-May-2020",
    creditPoint: 3,
    seminarEnrolment: [
      { studentID: "std004", enrolmentDate: "20-April-2020" },
      { studentID: "std002", enrolmentDate: "10-April-2020" },
    ],
  },
  student: [
    {
      studentID: "std004",
      studentName: "Klein Acevedo",
      address: "Block 23, Toa Payoh",
      telephone: [{ handphone1: "93589248", handphone2: "82354723" }],
      enrolTo: [{ seminarID: "sem004", markReceived: 64 }],
    },
    {
      studentID: "std002",
      studentName: "Selma Hobbs",
      address: "87 Pearl Hill",
      telephone: [{ handphone: "91647249", residentphone: "62691355" }],
      enrolTo: [{ seminarID: "sem004", markReceived: 89 }],
    },
  ],
});
```

With a simple collection of mongoDB above, i'm trying to do a simple find query below

```
db.studentSeminar.find({"seminarDescription": "In-memory Database."})
```

However, it's not returning anything, or showing up any error message

Can anyone help me? I'm still new to MongoDB
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the dot `.` operator, since `seminarDescription` is a nested field of a document.

The below will work for you:

```js
db.studentSeminar.find({
  "seminar.seminarDescription": "In-memory Database."
})
```